# How to retrieve hashtags from string using this PHP regex in Java?

Tags: java, php, regex

I am a PHP developer and it has been only a few months since I started learning Java. Here, I have a function in PHP to retrieve the hashtags from a string.

```
{
    preg_match_all('/(^|[^a-z0-9_])#([a-z0-9_]+)/i', $text, $matchedHashtags);
    $hashtag = '';
    if (!empty($matchedHashtags[0])) {
        foreach ($matchedHashtags[0] as $match) {
            $hashtag .= preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]+/i", "", $match) . ',';
        }
    }
    return rtrim($hashtag, ',');
}
```

This function returns a new strings containing the hashtags, separated by a comma. My question is, how to achieve this exact function in java? Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option might be to use a single pattern, instead of first matching and then replacing.

Then you can either concatenate the results in a string, or add the results to a list and use `String.join` with a comma.

```
\B#\w*[A-Za-z]\w*
```

- `\B` Match at a position where `\b` does not match
- `#\w*[A-Za-z]\w*` Match `#` and at least a single char A-Za-z (if you don't want to match only digits or underscores according to the comments)

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/KZIvdX) | [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dSPaTl/1)

For example

```
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\B#\\w*[A-Za-z]\\w*")
    .matcher("#test @#$#test a#test,#2021, #__");
while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group());
}

System.out.println(String.join(",", matches));
```

Output

```
#test1,#test2
```

Comment: Thank You. The reason why I asked for the Java replacement of that particular regex is that, it seems to be the standard one used by Twitter, Facebook and Instagram etc. For example, using your regex, hashtags with numbers or special characters, such as #2021, #__ gets considered as a hashtag. So what can be the solution for this issue?

Comment: @WebDiva You could for example match at least a single char A-Za-z `\B#\w*[A-Za-z]\w*` See https://regex101.com/r/2ZNlt6/2

Comment: Thank You! Regex was always a thing that bothered me, irrespective of the language. I have been figuring this out for a whole day. Once again, Thank You.